# How can I associate cities with countries only using lists and not using dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with cities and countries.

```
List1=['Athens', 'Sidney']

List2=['Greece', 'Australia']

c=raw_ input('Enter a city: ')
```

Athens is in Greece and Sidney is in Australia.

How can I test if Sidney is in Australia using just lists and not dictionaries?

Comment: But a better way would be to keep dictionary. Make country name key and assign a list of cities to it as value

Comment: You can Zip the lists to create tuples, or you can index the lists, but this only really works with a 1:1 relationship so this is not really a scalable approach.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you could do:

```
result = [country for city,country in zip(List1,List2) if city == c]
if result:
    print('This city is in {}'.format(result[0]))
else:
    print('City not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others: the best way to approach this is to use a dictionary. However, if you still insist on keeping two separate lists:

```
cities = ['Athens', 'Sidney']
countries = ['Greece', 'Australia']
user_city = raw_input('Enter a city: ')

try:
    country = countries[cities.index(user_city)]
    print user_city, 'is in', country
except ValueError:
    print user_city, 'is not in the list of cities'
```

Notes

- The expression `cities.index(user_city)` will return the index position for `user_city` within the `cities` list. However, if the `user_city` is not in the list, a `ValueError` exception will occur. That is why I handle it below.
- With that index, I can now look up the country and print out the result

Answer (score 0):

`zip` two lists, form a dictionary and check for the sydney key!

```
myHash=dict(zip(List1, List2))
myHash.has_key("Sidney")
```

Prints `True` if present else `False`